# how to use PDO rowCount() function in foreach?

Tags: php, pdo

i need some help , i have simple code like  count rows  in php, i use PDO ,

so i check if `rowCount >` 0 i do job if no other job but i have it in `foreach` function, in first step i get true result but in other i get invalid

so i think  it is function like a `closeCursor()` in PDO but i try  and no matter . maybe i  do it wrong ?

it is part of my code

```
public function saveClinicCalendar($post){
    $daysItm = '';
    $Uid =  $post['Uid'];
    $ClinicId =  $post['ClinicId'];
    $type =  $post['type'];
    $resChck = '';

    foreach($post['objArray'] as $arr){
        foreach($arr['days'] as $days){
            $daysItm = $days.",".$daysItm;
        }

        $daysItm = substr($daysItm, 0, -1);
        $dateTime = $arr['dateTime'];

        $sqlChck = 'SELECT * FROM clinic_weeks WHERE dates = :dates AND Uid = :Uid AND category = :category AND Cid = :Cid AND type = :type';
        $resChck = $this->db->prepare($sqlChck);
        $resChck->bindValue(":dates",$dateTime);
        $resChck->bindValue(":Cid",$ClinicId);
        $resChck->bindValue(":type",$type);
        $resChck->bindValue(":Uid",$Uid);
        $resChck->bindValue(":category",$Uid);

        $resChck->execute();
        $co = $resChck->rowCount();

        if($co > 0){
            /*UPDATE*/

            $sql = 'UPDATE clinic_weeks SET dates = :dates ,time = :time, Cid = :Cid, type  = :type, Uid = :Uid, category = :category   ';
            $res = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $res->bindValue(":dates",$dateTime);
            $res->bindValue(":time",$daysItm);
            $res->bindValue(":Cid",$ClinicId);
            $res->bindValue(":type",$type);
            $res->bindValue(":Uid",$Uid);
            $res->bindValue(":category",$Uid);

        }else{
            /*INSERT*/

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO clinic_weeks (dates,time, Cid,type,Uid,category) VALUES (:dates,:time, :Cid,:type,:Uid,:category)';
            $res = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $res->bindValue(":dates",$dateTime);
            $res->bindValue(":time",$daysItm);
            $res->bindValue(":Cid",$ClinicId);
            $res->bindValue(":type",$type);
            $res->bindValue(":Uid",$Uid);
            $res->bindValue(":category",$Uid);
        }

        $res->execute();
        $resChck->closeCursor();

        $resChck = null;

        $daysItm = '';
    }
}
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you making use of `$item` variable in your foreach loop ?

Comment: i write foreach for example that i use it  and  more important that  code is in a cicle  and it`s my problem i guess

 





    }

Comment: What exactly is not working here ?

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of doing a `SELECT` first?

Comment: how can i get  items from sql  at first if i do not do SELECT? is it any other way to comparison sql data and  my new data ?

Answer (score -1):

many thanks  to  **Barmar**, he suggest me a true answer.
here is a code

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO clinic_weeks
       (`timestam`,`time`,dates,Cid,type,Uid,category)
       VALUES
       ('$timestamp','$daysItm','$dateTime','$ClinicId','$type','$Uid','$Uid')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `time` =  '$daysItm' ";
```

I use there "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" and it`s work perfectly!
instead a big code top of page i make a two line of code.